# Azure Powershell Select-AzureSubscription with subscription id

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am using Powershell Azure cmdlets to do some operation on each subscription I have.

**However, all  my subscriptions have the same name.** So if I do an operation like:

```
$subs | ForEach-Object {
    Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionName $_.SubscriptionName
    $services = Get-AzureService
    Write-Output "$($services .Length) services under $($_.SubscriptionId) subscription"
}
```

it always works for the same subscription because the subscriptions only differ in subscription ID.

And the `Select-AzureSubscription` does not have a `-SubscriptionId` parameter.

Any ideas how can I find a workaround?

Comment: You can use Set-AzureSubscription and based on SubscriptionId, you can set a valid name. Then use that name in rest of the code.

Comment: @ramiramilu can you please add that as an answer? I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the publishsettings file, giving each subscription a different name. Then re-import. At that point, you'll be able to easily access each one uniquely by name.

Comment: This did not work for me.  `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` with just changing the name left the name with the original name when imported instead of the new one.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this was added later, but as of Nov 2015 you can use `-SubscriptionId`

```
Write-Host "Selecting Azure subscription using id"
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

Comment: @Rick! I am executing powershel script to azure gov cloud that I downloaded from azure portal. I am getting this error - Select-AzureRmSubscription : Provided subscription 8888888408e8 does not exist

Answer (score 4):

If you are an account administrator for your account, you can change the name of your subscription.  This way when you or anyone else who has access to the subscription downloads publishsettings, the name will be set the way you want.

http://rickrainey.com/windows-azure-how-tos/how-to-change-the-name-of-your-windows-azure-subscription/